# Minimized windows to appear as "half-icons" in hidden launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, minimize

I was wondering if there is a way of having the minimized windows displayed in launcher as "half icons"?

Something like this:

[image]

but for all applications.

I like to have the launcher hidden most of the time, and I'd find it much more productive to see what windows I have opened and have a constant access to see what is the application doing (i.e. chrome downloads).

It doesn't have to be Unity (but would be preferred).

Comment: it's up and running from here... here's a mirror: http://oi38.tinypic.com/jt6tqe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool). You can change the icon size of the dock, plus much more hidden settings of Unity.

Comment: There are no options for something I'm looking for in UTT.

Comment: Doing exactly what you want to do is impossible. If you want to save space on your screen while still seeing application icons you can decrease the size of the icons in Unity tweak tool.